# cordova build android failed Windows 7

Tags: cordova

When running `cordova build android` (Windows 7) I get the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
 option to get more log output.

Total time: 7.631 secs
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\foo\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\foo\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
```

The problem is clearly that it's trying to run `platforms\android\gradlew` instead of `platforms\android\gradlew.bat` as this is Windows and not unix/macos. When I run node `process.platform` returns "win32". What could be the problem?